# How to close opened port without closing the process

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm trying to close the connection without closing the process.

For example:

```
Close(LocalEndPoint.Address,
      RemoteEndPoint.Address,
      LocalEndPoint.Address.port,
      RemoteEndPoint.Address.port)
```

I got the list of all opened connections:
(http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14423/Getting-the-active-TCP-UDP-connections-using-the-G)

and now I want to make usefull software (close every connection if process id is 0).
I don't know how to do it without closing the process that responsible to the connection.

There is a software named: **CurrPorts**, this software is closing connections without closing the process.
Which function can close connection without the making user to notice? (`user32.dll`)(c# or vb.net)

Good example is better than a good explanation.

Comment: use apimonitor to find out what CurrPorts does to close the ports

Comment: Here is a [link to apimonitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) in case you needed it.

Comment: It is a really BAD idea to close another processes connections.  They are not yours to close.